# How to find the angle of X and Y and then plot a line transecting each grid lines at a variable angle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I am trying to work out how to find the angles labelled in the image.
I would then like to be able to plot a line intersecting the y or x-axis with a variable angle, say 20 degrees?

I think finding the angle of intersections first is the bit that could then help me work out how to do the variable bit myself.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

x = np.linspace(-5,5, 100)

plt.plot(x, -1.5*x+20, '-r', label='y=2x+1')

plt.plot(x, 2.5*x+4, '-r', label='y=2x+1')

plt.show()
```

**Edit**

Here is an attempt to rearange the formula given in the correct answer.

[formula rearranged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAWcg.jpg)

and my attempt to codify it, but it breaks.

```
my_angle = 45
gradient = np.arctan**(np.pi * my_angle/180 + np.pi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know the slopes of your two lines, you can simply compute the inverse tan of the slopes to get the angles. You can then multiply with `180 / np.pi` to get the values in degrees.

```
import numpy as np

angle1 = np.arctan(2.5) * 180 / np.pi # angle in degrees

# 68.19859051364818 

angle2 =  180 - abs(np.arctan(-1.5) * 180 / np.pi) # angle in degrees

# 123.69006752597979
```

Comment: Note that these are the angles in "axes space". Here they are quite different from the angles in screen space.

Comment: @JohanC : I didn't get the point. The slope of line is w.r.t the x-axis and that is what matters, right?

Comment: Yes, they are w.r.t. the x-axis, measured as if the image is drawn 1:1 in x and y, as if `plt.axis('equal')` would be set. Your answer is correct, but I think OP should also be informed about why an angle that looks 33° on the screen is in reality 68°.

Comment: @JohanC Totally agree!

Comment: It seems that OP has not oriented lines so using `arctan(dy/dx)` is fine, otherwise I'd recommend `arctan2(dy, dx)`

Comment: Thanks for that and I appreciate the 'equal' info.